# WooCommerce: Remove sidebar for category pages on Twenty twelve child theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, sidebar

I would like to remove the sidebar on WooCommerce category pages and make the products there full width. I would very much appreciate any help with what code to put where. I have tried googling but haven't been able to get anything to work.

I am using a Twenty twelve child theme.
[happilyprinted.com](http://happilyprinted.com)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the sidebar from category page override **archive-product.php** in your current theme in WordPress.

Instead of editing these files directly within the plugin (which is a very bad idea because once update the plugin and all of your changes will be lost!), you can copy them into your theme:

- In your theme directory, make a new folder called “woocommerce.”
- Navigate to the WooCommerce plugin directory and open the "templates" folder. The templates folder has a lot of subfolders with all of the different templates that WooCommerce uses. Fortunately, the template file structure and naming in WooCommerce is easy to follow.
- In your newly created "woocommerce" folder, copy the template file that you want to edit.

> Remember to keep the directory structure the same here. If the
>   template you want to edit is within a subfolder then remember to
>   create that subfolder within your theme's directory.

go to **wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/woocommerce**

edit the file **archive-product.php** remove the following code -

```
<?php
/**
 * woocommerce_sidebar hook
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
 */
do_action('woocommerce_sidebar');?>
```

Next, we have to edit the **style.css** in your theme folder-

```
.woocommerce .wrapper .site-content
    {
            width: 100%;
    }
```

- Edit the **archive-product.php** file from within your “woocommerce” folder and save the changes.